# Performance: create collection from scratch or iterate and add missing? (Java)

Tags: java, collections

A quick question: which is preferable, either performance-wise or programming-wise:

Situation: 
You have a table in a database which contains information about an object, for example:
Table `Car` which has columns `Id` (PK), `Brand`, `Colour`.

You have a program that displays information about the cars in your database. You can select a `Brand` and it shows you all the cars from that brand. A call to the database is performed to get this information. Every car that is displayed is made into an Object `Car` in your program, with the corresponding attributes, and added to the Collection `CarCollection` (ArrayList). Next time you need information about a specific `Car`, the program first checks if the `Car` is in the collection. If this is not the case, a call to the database is done.

So you end up with a Collection of `Cars`. Now I want to display all the `Cars` I have in my database. They may all be in the `CarCollection` already, but that is not certain.

What is preferable:

- Use a query to select all `Cars`, clear the contents of the existing `CarCollection` and fill the collection from scratch
- Use a query to select all `Cars`, iterate through the `CarCollection` and the database result and add those that are missing
- Use a query that only selects the `Cars` not in the collection and add those

Extra note: Collection.contains() yields only false, it does not recognize the objects on the list as the same that are in the collection (even if this is the case).
Another extra note: The idea behind the collection was to minimalize calls to the database. If an object is already in the collection, a database call is no longer needed.

Suggestions for a completely different approach are of course also welcome.

Comment: Try phrasing your requirements more clearly. Also, this likely depends on the type of the collection (a hashset has very different performance characteristics than an arraylist ...)

Comment: I have added an example to clarify what I meant. I hope this is more clear!

Comment: I don't know why, but this little bug in my brain keeps asking "Why isn't he just using [JPA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence)?"

Answer (score 2):

> `Collection.contains()` yields only false

Then you probably need to override equals and hashcode on your objects.

> The idea behind the collection was to minimalize calls to the database

Let's assume that your objects have an id, why not call a

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id NOT IN (<the list of ids that you already have>)
```

?

Comment: Override equals is a good one, didn't think of that. Your other suggestion is also something I overlooked, and I added it to my post.

Comment: Overriding equals has indeed solved the problem of Collection.contains(). Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more clear on phrasing the requirement. It is easy to find the missing object.

First point here is how to define the object. Means how uniquely you will identify the objects. Then define equals() and hashcode() methods are implemented.

```
public class Entity{
     private int id;
     ......
     .......

     public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(!(obj instanceof Entity)){
           return false;
        }
        EntityObj eobj = (Entity)obj;

        return (id==eobj.id);

     }

     public int hashcode(){
        return id; //Any hashing function is fine
     }    

}
```

Once you have object defined. You just need to fetch all the elements from Database and compare with the collection elements and find the missing.

Collection needs to be used for searching depends on your requirement. If it is List interface you need to iterate them is time consuming.  For any searching it is better to use hashing function for fast Search.